# Excel VBA ADODB RecordSet changes Field types from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, recordset

I am running a simple query on a SQL Server table:

`SELECT * FROM MyTable`

The table contains three columns, with types `int`, `bit`, and `datetime2(0)`. I am using code along the lines of:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB RecordSet
Dim rngDest As Range
:
: ' etc
:
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM MyTable", cnn
rngDest.CopyFromRecordset rst
```

This works well, ***except*** that it seems to be **getting the field types wrong**: it says the field types are 3, 11, 202, which are, according to the documentation, **Integer** (correct), **Boolean** (correct, I guess), and **NVarChar2** -- incorrect. The third field should be a ***date***, surely ("Date" type is 135).

As background: I migrated the data from Access to SQL Server using SSMA. This table now has the three column types I mentioned. Also, I understand that it is a well-known problem that CopyFromRecordset can get the field types wrong, and I initially thought that was why the third column (the date) was appearing in Excel as a string, but upon closer inspection I can see that when the VBA has read the Recordset it already believes the field is text, before the CopyFromRecordset line. I feel if I could get the VBA to somehow recognise that the third field should be a date then I could convert it internally. I would rather not create a solution for this table specifically because I have many, many Tables and Views that have to be handled, so I would prefer to find an approach that works for all of them.

If it's important, the connection string I am using is:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=[REDACTED];Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=[REDACTED];
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: How does your date data look?

Comment: It looks like this in the database: ```2020-03-02 14:05:11```, and when it is read from the database it is a text field looking the same as that. I can intercept it in the VBA code using eg ```DateValue(rst.Fields(2).Value``` but I feel that's a little over the top and I need to know that the field is indeed a date, which the ```.Type``` property should tell me but instead it tells me it's text.

Comment: your answer is good.  I added  answer. A different solution has been suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backwards compatible SQLOLEDB driver that ships with Windows has no notion SQL Server data types introduced over the last 20 years, like `date`. Try the latest SQL Server OLEDB driver, [MSOLEDBSQL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56730).

I ran a quick ADO test using the VbScript below and a `date` column returned ADO type 133 (`adDBDate`).

```
Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connection.Open "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI"
Set recordset = connection.Execute("SELECT CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS date);")
MsgBox recordset.Fields(0).Type
connection.Close
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I am in an environment where I can't make changes like this but I will get in touch with the support guys and see whether they are willing to do this.

Comment: The new OLEDB driver installs side-by-side with the legacy one so there shouldn't be a problem if the OS is compatible. You will need to test the app code with the new driver, though.

Comment: Ah. Well the first thing I did was try it and the error message was ```Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.```. I'll see what they say.

Comment: Further: I ran the Powershell script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37849324/4799336) and it isn't in the resulting output -- but when I ran it on my personal laptop it was. So I need to talk to the support guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your date field may be string.  so  you convert the date.  The following example converts a character date to date data. You will need to specify differently depending on what your character type is.

> 20130604060133   ->   2013/06/04 06:01:33

```
select
  convert(datetime,SUBSTRING( '20130604060133',1,8),112) +
  convert(datetime,
   ( substring( '20130604060133',9,2) + ':' +
    substring( '20130604060133',11,2)  + ':' +
    substring( '20130604060133',13,2)  )
    ,120) as myDate
```

The problem seems to be somewhere else, but it's not clear. But there is a way to change the data. See below.

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rngDest As Range
:
: ' etc
:
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM MyTable", cnn
rngDest.CopyFromRecordset rst

Dim vDB
Dim rngDB As Range
Set rngDB = rngDest.CurrentRegion
vDB = rngDB
rngDB.NumberFormat = "General"
rngDB = vDB
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and changing the format to General didn't change the date/times for me. What did work is using PasteSpecial to add 0, but for operational reasons I want to avoid using the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have found to work (while I'm waiting for the support guys to update the driver):
[TL;DR: Read the Recordset into a variant `varOrig` using `rst.GetRows`; transpose, then plonk into an Excel sheet; using `.Value2 =` causes Excel to convert it to a proper date. [We have to transpose because `.GetRows`, despite its name, returns columns of data.]]

Hope this is useful for anyone else in the future having a similar problem.

```
Public Sub RecordSetToRange(ByRef rst As ADODB.Recordset, ByRef lobDst As ListObject)

    Const strROUTINE As String = "RecordSetToRange"
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim varOrig As Variant
    Dim varTxp() As Variant

    ' -- Error Handling, Validation, Initialization.
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    ' -- Procedure.

    ' Headers first.
    With lobDst.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1)
        For iCol = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
            .Offset(0, iCol).Value2 = rst.Fields(iCol).Name
        Next iCol
    End With
    ' Then data. Note that, despite the name of the function, GetRows returns columns of data, so we have
    ' to transpose it. Don't do anything if there is no data.
    If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
        varOrig = rst.GetRows
        ReDim varTxp(UBound(varOrig, 2), UBound(varOrig, 1))
        For iRow = 0 To UBound(varOrig, 2)
            For iCol = 0 To UBound(varOrig, 1)
                varTxp(iRow, iCol) = varOrig(iCol, iRow)
            Next iCol
        Next iRow
        lobDst.DataBodyRange.Resize(UBound(varOrig, 2) + 1, UBound(varOrig, 1) + 1).Value2 = varTxp
    End If
    '
ErrHandler:        ' -- Error handling and Routine termination.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then If DspErr(mstrMODULE, strROUTINE) Then Stop: Resume Else End
End Sub
```

Comment: if recordset has no null data,  you can directly write to cell wtithout loop.  lobDst.DataBodyRange.Resize(UBound(varOrig, 2) + 1, UBound(varOrig, 1) + 1)=  application.transpose(varOrig)

Comment: That's right, thank you, but ```Application.Transpose``` has a row limit of 65,536 and I don't know whether my data would always be within that limit.